# Prevent HTML element reload when concatenating HTML using innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form having two input fields:

```
<form id="import-products-form">
  <div class="form-row">
    <select></select>
    <input>
  </div>
</form>
```

And a button:

```
<button id="add-input-button"><strong>+</strong></button>
```

Everytime the button is clicked, two input fields will be added to the form:

```
document.getElementById("add-input-button").onclick = () => {
  const input = `
    <div class="form-row">
      <select></select>
      <input>
    </div>
  `;

  document.getElementById("import-products-form").innerHTML += input;
};
```

The problem here is whenever the button is clicked, the values of the existed fields will be reset to default. In `DevTools`, I saw that the entire form was reloaded when the button clicked.
Is there anyway to keep the values of the existed fields when new fields added to the form?

Comment: Use `type="button"` so the button doesn't submit the form.

Comment: the button is not the child of form element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't assign to `innerHTML`. That causes all the elements inside the form to be recreated from scratch, and any dynamic state is lost.

Use [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) instead. This parses the new HTML and appends the DOM elements, without disturbing the original elements.

```
document.getElementById("import-products-form").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', input);
```

Comment: Nice, it works perfectly. And I just corrected the code syntax. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`x.innerHTML += input` effectively runs 
`x.innerHTML = (x.innerHTML + input)` and you lose the state

---

You should create new element and append it.

```js
document.getElementById("add-input-button").onclick = (e) => {
   const input = `
     <select></select>
     <input>
   `;
   let div = document.createElement('div')
   div.classList.add('form-row')
   div.innerHTML=input
   document.getElementById("import-products-form").appendChild(div)
};
```

```html
<form id="import-products-form">
  <div class="form-row">
    <select></select>
    <input>
  </div>
</form>
<button id="add-input-button"><strong>+</strong></button>
```

---

For this specific use case, no need to create element from text every time.

```js
{
   const input = `
     <select></select>
     <input>
   `;
   let div = document.createElement('div')
   div.classList.add('form-row')
   div.innerHTML=input

   document.getElementById("add-input-button").onclick = (e) => {
      document.getElementById("import-products-form").appendChild(div.cloneNode(true))
   };
}
```

```html
<form id="import-products-form">
  <div class="form-row">
    <select></select>
    <input>
  </div>
</form>
<button id="add-input-button"><strong>+</strong></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `appendChild` instead of `innerHTML`.

```js
document.getElementById("add-input-button").onclick = () => {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  var select = document.createElement('select');
  var input = document.createElement('input');
  div.classList.add('form-row');
  div.appendChild(select);
  div.appendChild(input);

  document.getElementById("import-products-form").appendChild(div);
};
```

```html
<form id="import-products-form">
  <div class="form-row">
    <select></select>
    <input>
  </div>
</form>

<button id="add-input-button"><strong>+</strong></button>
```